# Cast boost::array<float, 12> for function with argument (const float (&arr)[12])

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, casting

I have a `boost::array<float, 12>` that I want to use as input to a function whos signature is:

```
Foo(const float(&arr)[12])
```

I've tried getting the data elements from the boost::array via `.data()` but this returns a float pointer which won't fit my signature. I can change the function signature need be but would prefer not to. Ideas?

Comment: cheat and reinterpret?  might even be legal under layout compatibility, not sure.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code will compile:

```
#include <array>

void f(int (&arr)[4])
{
}

int main() 
{
    std::array<int, 4> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    f(*reinterpret_cast<int (*)[4]>(arr.data()));
    return 0;
}
```

The trick is to cast the `int*` returned by `arr.data()` to a "pointer to an array" (i.e. `int (*)[4]`) by using `reinterpret_cast`. You then dereference this to get a "reference" to that array.

**Edit:** It might be better to use a template like the one below, to ensure that the pointer is cast to the appropriate array type.

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
T (&as_simple_array(std::array<T, N>& arr))[N] {
    return *reinterpret_cast<T (*)[N]>(arr.data());
}
```

You'd then use it like this:

```
f(as_simple_array(arr));
```

Comment: I can't imagine this not working in practice, but are you sure this is strictly legal?

Comment: @Praetorian I am not a language lawyer so I can't say for sure, but on a basic analysis I can't see any problem with this: the element types and the array sizes are both the same.

Comment: @dyp: I may understand that casting `array` may be problematic, but also the `data()` ?

Answer (score 3):

The [synopsis](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/array.html) says that the actual array is named `elems`, so this should work:

```
Foo(my_array.elems);
```

It's unclear from this whether the member is guaranteed to be so named, or whether it's "exposition only" like certain members in the standard. At any rate, the following should work, but it's ugly:

```
Foo(reinterpret_cast<const float (&)[12]>(my_array[0]));
```

---

**This is well-defined in C++14.** A `reinterpret_cast` to reference has the same semantics as the corresponding `reinterpret_cast` to pointer ([expr.reinterpret.cast]/11),

```
*reinterpret_cast<const float (*)[12]>(&my_array[0])
```

This reinterpret cast is in turn equivalent to a double `static_cast` ([expr.reinterpret.cast]/7):

```
static_cast<const float (*)[12]>(static_cast<const void*>(&my_array[0]))
```

The conversion to *cv* `void` is guaranteed to give a pointer to the first byte of the object ([conv.ptr]/2). The subsequent conversion to `const float (*)[12]` is also guaranteed to give a pointer to the same byte as long as the address is appropriately aligned for an object of the target type ([expr.static.cast]/13), which must be the case since it was originally the address of an array.

Comment: If the standard says "exposition only" then it is. Otherwise, it's required to be there. My copy of the C++11 standard (N3290) says `T elems[N]; // exposition only`

Comment: @MarshallClow, the OP is using `boost::array`, not `std::array`.

Comment: D'oh! Sorry about that.